# How to load the details from database to a dropdown field in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

```
company_name=fields.One2many(string="Enter your company name", select=True, comodel_name ='companydb')
```

I tried like this, but it gives only database name in the field, instead of company name...

My database is as follows...

```
`class Company_Data(models.Model):
    _name="companydb"

    companyname=fields.Char(string="Enter the name of the company")
    companyID=fields.Char(string="Enter the ID of company")`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got the direction wrong: you want a Many2one there.

```
company_name=fields.Many2one('companydb', string="Enter your company name")
```

also you want to define `_rec_name` on the other model (or rename the `companyname` field to `name`):

```
class CompanyData(models.Model)
    _name = 'companydb'
    _rec_name = 'companyname'
    ...
```

Final advice: avoid mixing naming conventions (underscores, camel case...)